# Difference in opening a website in a machine using ip address and localhost?

Tags: javascript, security, internet-explorer, google-chrome, web

I have a website configured in my IIS.

In the browser(Internet Explorer) when I open(*in the same machine where is the website hosted in IIS*) it by giving url with localhost it opens correctly, but when I give the IP address it displays me a pop up

> "Content from the website listed below is being blocked by the
>   internet explorer Enhanced security Configuration"

What is the logical difference when a website is being opened by giving localhost and when a user gives a IP?

Also the OS is Windows Server 2008

Comment: `localhost` is a special thing, it usually always points to the local machine. With a LAN IP, the site will be treated like any other 3rd party site.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in permissions and in trust. In localhost, you're the only person viewing, and editing your file. Your browser is configured to automatically trust everything on your own computer if you give it the permissions. However, something on your page is throwing a security exception on IE when you try to access it on another computer.

Localhost is put in your local intranet zone, so it is automatically trusted every time, as opposed to someone trying to access an IP on another computer

Answer (score 1):

In IE, by default `localhost` is added to your `Local Intranet` zone, which runs at a lower security setting (Medium-Low) than other sites (High).

Certain things such as Active-X and some scripts don't function at the High security setting.

If you wish to, you can [add the site to your `Local Intranet` zone](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815141#62).

Technically, accessing your site at Localhost, the traffic goes through the loopback interface that is restricted to just your machine. Accessing the site via your network interface's IP address, of course, accesses the website through the network adapter.

Comment: I am opening the website in the same machine where the website is being hosted and then I am getting this pop up.

Comment: @Mozak, understood. You still need to add the IP address/host name to the Local Interanet zone or only use functionality that works in the High security zone.

Comment: I have a windows server 2008 machine, is there any possibility that a group policy may be causing it?